# Cocoa How to know if a file was edited/closed

Tags: objective-c

I open a file programmatically with the default application taking into account the file extension. 
When the file is open, I need to know when the file is modified and when is no longer in use.
I used FSEventStreamCreate to create the event.
How can I know if the file was closed?

Thanks,
Ana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to see if my file was modified:

```
    NSString * modified = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fileAttributes objectForKey:@"NSFileModificationDate"]];
    NSString * savedmod = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kFeedLastModified"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:modified forKey:@"kFeedLastModified"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    if (![savedmod isEqualToString:modified])
     {
          NSlog(@"File modified");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the modified date of the file.

Comment: I checked for the modified date to know if the file was updated, but I don´t know how to check if the file was closed.